# If default tab is selected in init then tabselect event handler doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm working with jquery ui tabs and trying to set the 'selected' tab to 0 on initialization but it isn't firing the tabselect event.  If I set the 'selected' tab to 1 or any other tab the tabselect event will fire. My thinking was that since the 0 index tab is the default setting the 'selected' tab to the default doesn't fire the tabselect event because it's already selected. Am I right in thinking this? And, is there a way to make this work in the context of the ui-tabs utility?

```
divRelationships.tabs({
    select: function (e, ui) {
        createRelationshipListBoxForWebObject(divRelationships, webObjectGuid, ui);
    }
});
divRelationships.tabs("select", 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `show` or `create` events depending on your needs (`show` seems closer to what you want). `show` will be called whenever "Tab 0" is shown (including on initialization of the tabs widget).

With that in mind, you wouldn't have to manually trigger the `select` event. The following should suffice:

```
divRelationships.tabs({
    show: function (e, ui) {
        createRelationshipListBoxForWebObject(divRelationships, webObjectGuid, ui);
    }
});

// Show will automatically be called when the tabs widget is created.
```